# На новых Super Retina Display (Iphone X) растровый пиксель (bitmap pixel) так же умножается на 4?

Tags: html, css, iphone-x, retina

На новых Super Retina Display (Iphone X) растровый пиксель (bitmap pixel) так же умножается на 4?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, думаю вряд ли что то изменилось.

- Iphone 7 Plus (Retina): 1920x1080 пикселей, 401 пикселей на дюйм.
- Iphone X (Super Retina): 2436x1125 пикселей, 458 пикселей на дюйм.

Т.е. прирост плотности пикселей всего 15%.